# Why does NickServ on FreeNode IRC ask me to identify every day?

Tags: empathy, irc

I am using Empathy as an IRC client.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

FreeNode will [require you to authenticate](http://freenode.net/faq.shtml#registering) to NickServ each time you connect to the network to be recognised as a registered user, so most likely you are occasionally being disconnected.

If you would like to identify with NickServ automatically, you can use your nickname password as the network password when connecting to the network.

In Empathy, this can be done with the following steps:

1. Choose `Accounts` from the `Edit` menu.
2. Select your FreeNode IRC account from the accounts list.
3. Click the `Edit Connection Parameters...` button.
4. Enter `$master_nickname:$nickserv_password` in the `Password` field (substituting the correct values), and click `Apply`.

Once this is done, you should be able to verify that you get identified by disconnecting and reconnecting: NickServ should tell you that you have successfully identified shortly after connecting.

Comment: Thanks. It works, but NickServ still sends me a message that I need to identify, just before telling me that I have been identified. At least I do not have to type the password anymore.

Comment: It always does that.  I don't think there is any way to turn that behaviour off.

Comment: Why this is not highlighted in the docs I don't know, just wasted hours... Thank you!!

Comment: Crazy this absolutely needs to be documented better. I've been searching for this for EOOOONS! Live saver buddy!